# How to find duplicate keys from a List<KeyValuePair<byte[], string>> fileHashList = new List<KeyValuePair<byte[], string>>();

Tags: c#, linq

I've a lsit of type `List<KeyValuePair<byte[], string>> fileHashList = new List<KeyValuePair<byte[], string>>();`

```
foreach (string entry in results)
{
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine("DirectoryPath"), entry));
    using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileInfo.FullName))
        {
            var hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
            fileHashList.Add(new KeyValuePair<byte[], string>(hash, fileInfo.FullName)); 
        }
    }
}
```

I need to find all the duplicate keys in this list.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16049614/finding-duplicate-key-in-a-list-of-keyvaluepair) but doesn't work in my case, I get `"Enumeration yielded no results"` even though I've same keys!

Let me know if any additional data is needed
Thanks

Comment: it doesn't make sens .. as byte[] are compared by ref

Comment: Because `GroupBy` uses the default comparer, and for a byte array that's useless as it compares the object hash, which is different for arrays of equal content. See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841178/group-by-array-contents). Why do you have a byte array as key anyway?

Comment: Please let me know how should I proceed, I mean in which direction

Comment: See duplicates, use `.GroupBy(k => k.Key, StructuralComparisons.StructuralEqualityComparer)`.

Comment: var duplicates = fileHashList.GroupBy(x => x.Key).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng try reading the question and the comments. This will invoke the default equality comparer, which will not yield the same hash for arrays with the same contents. That code does not do any grouping, all keys will be reported as being different.

Comment: @CodeCaster So do I need mandatorily need to override  the `GetHashCode()` method or just over riding the  `Equals()` method is enough?
Also the reason I'm having byte array as key because those are hashcode and I wish to check if multiple files are same or not.

Comment: You can't override those for an array, you need to provide a custom comparer, see my other comment.

Comment: @CodeCaster I used your other comment but I get `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEqualityComparer' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<byte[]>'`

Comment: Yeah that's wrong, sorry. The quick fix would still be to create a custom comparer as in the first duplicate's accepted answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster I created a custom comparer but I'm struggling to use it as I wish.
I need to find all the duplicates as asked in the question

Comment: @CodeCaster Can you just write the usage line for me as per my need as marked in your duplicate

Comment: `var duplicates = fileHashList.GroupBy(x => x.Key, new ArrayComparer<byte>()).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222022/discussion-between-m-beta-and-codecaster).

Comment: No, [edit] your question to show what you have and why it doesn't work. It also won't hurt to have a [mre], where you initialize the list with some sample data.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, just a last query from my side.
I would like to fetch all the duplicate records (key value pair)
eg: [0,1], [0,2], [0,3] so since key is duplicate I would like to have all these 3 records fetched not just one
Your query is fetching me only one record (with key only)
I want all duplicate records with key value pair

Comment: @CodeCaster I've updated my question as you asked. Please reply on my last comment

Comment: You haven't added the relevant code. We don't have your files. A [mre] would contain a collection initialization with some example byte arrays and strings, and then the code you use to do the grouping. Anyhow, a GroupBy returns a collections of groupings, with `Key` being the key and its values (enumerable) the items that have the same key. So something like `foreach (var d in duplicates) { var filesWithSameHash = d.ToList(); }`.